# What is the best way to store Retrofit network call in Room Database

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-room

I am using MVVM architecture, Room Database and Retrofit. I want to store list of Genres which i fetch from the network and store them in the RoomDB. I want to use LiveData to get list of genres from the database. I understand that this kind of operation should be done within my repository class. I have a slight perspective how to do this, but i am not completely sure how to implement it.

Any advice or help is welcome. Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe this is helpful https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-repository-pattern#0

Comment: Thank you very much, after a lot of thinking and busting my brains it did help out